# NET Core Server Side multiple session Blazor

Tags: session, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to host my Blazor application on my server. 
I spent all the summer on it and I just realized every time I open my website on new device it doesn't create a new session restarting from zero, but continues where I left it. The worst part is there is a login system behind it, so I feel super dumb at the moment.

I really need a big hint on how to fix this "not little" issue. 
Is there a way to make server create new session every time someone open the website (without making it loose to other users)?

The solution should be use a Client Template instead, but the performance are really to slow.

UPDATE: 
Accounts "user password" are:
 - user user 
 - test test

[Download project sample (requires Net Core 3.0)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hmQxNM5d8p1hY4drvvc6dZsaI8Xc2WZC)

**[SOLUTION]**  itminus found the solution to my issue.

You have also to add in `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs this `services.AddScoped<Storage>();`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<Storage>();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a solvable issue, but we need more information to solve it. Without being familiar at all with blazor, I would guess we'd need at a minimum to see some of the code-behind where you establish a session.

Comment: I added some little part of code

Comment: First Off, session isn't supported in SignalR apps... I'm not sure I understand your description. "on new device" means,  what ? A different browser, say first time you access your app using FF, and then, Google Chrome ? Care to explain... how does your app create new session ? How do you know that "a new session" is  "restarting from zero?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> every time I open my website on new device it doesn't create a new session restarting from zero, but continues where I left it.

I checkout your code and find that you're using Singleton Pattern to initialize the `Storage`. If I understand it correctly, this `Storage` singleton instance will be shared across different users (also across different devices). As this instance will be used to render the `Main.razor` page, there will be concurrency problems that you're experiencing now .

To fix that issue, the Storage instance should be limited within some specific connection. As you're using Blazor Server Side, you could register the Storage as a **[`Scoped Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-services-to-an-app)**:

> In Blazor Server apps, a scoped service registration is **scoped to the connection**. For this reason, using scoped services is preferred for services that should be scoped to the current user, even if the current intent is to run client-side in the browser.

Firstly, remove the static singleton instance :

```
public class Storage
{
    private static Storage instance;
    private Storage()                         
    {                                         
    }                                         
    public static Storage GetInstance()       
    {                                         
         if (Storage.instance == null)        
             Storage.instance = new Storage();
         return Storage.instance;             
     }                                        

    public List<Items>list {get;set;} = new List<Items>();
    public string password {get;set;}

}
```

Register this Class as a scoped service:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Storage>();
```

And then inject this service in your `Login.razor` and  `Main.razor` :

```
@inject project.Storage Storage
```

Finally, you need change all the `Storage.GetInstance().` to `Storage.`:

```cs
    Storage.list = Order;
    ...
    Storage.password = password;
```

---

I notice that you're also creating the `Importer`/`Additional` instance using the Singleton Pattern. I would suggest you should refactor them to use Service Injection in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution. There is also a little part where you have to add  ```services.AddScoped<Storage>();``` in Startup.cs. I wrote that in the main post.